# How to return the result from XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, return-value

I have following function to convert local file to base64. When I run it, it writes the result (`res`) to console. How can I return the content of `res` from the function, so I can use it in another one?

```
function convertToBase64() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();       
        xhr.open("GET", "1.jpg", true); 
        xhr.responseType = "blob";
        xhr.onload = function (e) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function(event) {
               var res = event.target.result;
               console.log(res);
        }
        var file = this.response;
        reader.readAsDataURL(file)
    };
    xhr.send()
}
```

(I am totally new in JavaScript.)

Comment: Via a callback or a promise

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can pass callback to your function to execute when file loaded

```
function convertToBase64(onLoad) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();       
        xhr.open("GET", "1.jpg", true); 
        xhr.responseType = "blob";
        xhr.onload = function (e) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function(event) {
               var res = event.target.result;
               console.log(res);
               onLoad(res);            // callback
        }
        var file = this.response;
        reader.readAsDataURL(file)
    };
    xhr.send()
}
```

now you can do this :

```
convertToBase64(function(res) {
    console.log('response loaded' , res);
});
```